# The elementwise square of subset of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have the following numpy array

```
np.array([[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]])
```

I want to compute the elementwise square of second column and third column only by retaining the first column as it is, yielding the result,

```
np.array([[1,  4,   9],
          [4, 25, 36]],
          [7, 64, 81]])
```

What have I tried
I extracted the first column.
then I extracted the second and third columns. found square, using `numpy.square` function.

```
arr1 = arr[:, 0]
arr2 = np.square(arr[:, 1:])
```

and then concatenated them

```
np.c_[arr1, arr2]
```

Is there a single step solution?

Answer (score 5):

Select all elements of the non-first column using `[:, 1:]`.

```
arr[:, 1:] **= 2
```